# WinRT - Word dictionary for textbox's too large

Tags: textbox, winrt-xaml

I have a Window 8 store application that I would like to be able to use an exteremely large custom dictionary of words for (1.2MB). We've been able to add words to the microsoft dictionary in a user's roaming profile located at:
C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Spelling\en-US\default.dic

but it looks like when that file is larger than 64KB it just doesn't work.

Does anyone have any suggestions to remedy this?

Comment: Is it just for your app? Add it as a Resource and read it in at the beginning. You can add it in whatever file format you want, then just load it at startup. Or, use a .resw, then load the resource using a ResourceLoader.

Comment: I want to use this dictionary for the "IsSpellCheckEnabled" property of the TextBox's. Is there a way to tap into those dictionary settings through the code?

Comment: Have you found a workaround for this?

Comment: You also commented on my forum post for this same topic. I have not found a work around :( sorry.